# Receiving jQuery body changes in Wicket

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wicket

I got a question here regarding Wicket and jQuery. I got a WebPage which is rendered and shown by Wicket. Within this page I got one "draggable" and one "droppable" component, in which the user should be able to move components. This is realized via jQuery. Additionally I got a "Save" button at the end of the WebPage, which should save the new values (if there are any), which means: the newly dropped items. But if I click on "Save" I don't see the newly dropped objects within Wicket, I still just see the objects which have been in the "droppable" area from the beginning on. Here some Code snippets:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="user">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Benutzer</h1>
        <div class="ui-widget-content" id="userList">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzername" id="userNameSearch" />
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" wicket:id="userList"><span
                    wicket:id="user" id="user"></span><span style="visibility: hidden;" wicket:id="userId" id="userId"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="project">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Benutzer im Projekt</h1>
        <div class="ui-widget-content" id="project">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="placeholder list-group-item"><span>Benutzer
                        in dieses Feld ziehen.</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item" wicket:id="usersInProjectList"><span
                    wicket:id="userInProject"></span><span style="visibility: hidden;" wicket:id="userInProjectId"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="save" wicket:id="save">Speichern</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#userList li").draggable({
            appendTo : "body",
            helper : "clone"
        });
        $("#project ul")
                .droppable(
                        {
                            activeClass : "ui-state-default",
                            hoverClass : "ui-state-hover",
                            accept : ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                            drop : function(event, ui) {
                                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                                var userName = ui.draggable.find("#user").text();
                                var userId = ui.draggable.find("#userId").text();
                                $("<li class=\"list-group-item new-project-member\" wicket:id=\"usersInProjectList\"><span wicket:id=\"userInProject\">"+userName+"</span><span style=\"visibility:hidden;\" wicket:id=\"userInProjectId\">"+userId+"</span></li>")
                                        .appendTo(this);
                                $(ui.draggable).remove();
                            }
                        }).sortable({
                    items : "li:not(.placeholder)",
                    sort : function() {
                        // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
                        // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
                    }
                });

        $('#userNameSearch')
                .keyup(
                        function() {
                            var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                            if (valThis == "") {
                                $('#userList li').show();
                            } else {
                                $('#userList li')
                                        .each(
                                                function() {
                                                    var text = $(this)
                                                            .text()
                                                            .toLowerCase();
                                                    (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(
                                                            this).show()
                                                            : $(this)
                                                                    .hide();
                                                });
                            }
                            ;
                        });
    });
</script>
```

Java Code (Wicket):

```
    ListView userListView = new ListView("userList", finalUserList) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            User user = (User) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("user", user.getLastname()+", "+user.getFirstname()));
            item.add(new Label("userId", user.getId()));
        }
    };

    ListView usersInProjectListView = new ListView("usersInProjectList", usersInProjectList) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            User user = (User) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("userInProject", user.getLastname()+", "+user.getFirstname()));
            item.add(new Label("userInProjectId", user.getId()));
        }
    };
    usersInProjectListView.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    add(new AjaxLink<Void>("save")
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
                {
                    System.out.println(target.getPage().get("usersInProjectList"));
                    //window.close(target);
                }
            });     
    add(userListView);
    add(usersInProjectListView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could somehow get the changes from the client to the server, for example using Ajax. You can fire a callback function that can be added via `AbstractAjaxBehaviour` (see detail  [here](http://wickedsource.org/2013/01/07/rolling-your-own-ajax-behavior-with-wicket/)), or maybe switch to  [wicket-dnd](https://github.com/svenmeier/wicket-dnd)

Comment: Thanks for that answer Rob. Will give it a try next time, I'll get to further development of that code and post my experiences here.